# os.walk .jpg only

Tags: python, os.walk

I only want filenames that end in .jpg or .pdf. How do I limit the file name search?

```
import os
from subprocess import call

for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.'):
    for filename in filenames:
        jpg = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
        call(["./curl_recognize.sh", jpg, jpg+".txt", "-f txt"])
```

Comment: Another option is possibly to use `find` with an `-exec` in bash or something

Answer (score 5):

```
import fnmatch
import os

for file in os.listdir('.'):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.txt'):
        print file
```

fnmatch is better than other methods, since it suppose unix like wildcard, include:

*= matches everything

?= matches any single character

[seq]= matches any character in seq

[!seq]= matches any character not in seq

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
for filename in filenames:
  if not filename.endswith('.jpg'):
    continue
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list of all the files at the end you could do something like this

```
filelist = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    filelist = filelist + [os.path.join(x,root) for x in files if x.endswith(('.jpg','.pdf'))]
```